# Is there a better way to cast a variable to 'const' after assignments?

Tags: c

I always use `const` to guard values that should not be assigned. Anyway, there are some cases that I may need to initialize a variable and then use it as a `const` value, in the same function. For example:

```
void foo() {
  int flags;
  /* ... */
  if (condition1) 
      flags |= 1;
  /* .... */
  if (conditionX)
      flags |= Y;
  /* .... */
  // start using flags as a const value
  const flags; // <<= I want something like this.
  const int c_flags = flags; // <<= What I have to do. The naming is annoying.
  /* ... */
}
```

Is there any way to improve this? Could be coding styles or advanced language features.

---

From @Potatoswatter: for C in gcc/clang (gnu style, say, -std=gnu11), Statement Expression can be used.

```
foo() {
  const int flags = ({
    int f = 0;
    if (X) f |= Y;
    /* ... update f ... */
    f;
  });
  /* use the `const` flags */
}
```

Comment: You can use `const_cast`.

Comment: @Shravan40 Use `static_cast` to add `const`. Only use `const_cast` to *remove* it, because it's a red flag.

Comment: You should tag C or C++, not both, some answers here cannot be applied to C.

Comment: I think that using 2 versions of a same local variable sounds like over engineering. If you have hard time tracking if you should assign to variable or not, your function is probably too big.

Comment: My bad. It was for C. Since the answers all go to C++, let it be...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider making a function that returns the value you want

```
const int flags = getFlags();
```

Or more object oriented make a flags class that does that in the constructor.

```
const Flags flags(condition1, ...);
```

Answer (score 9):

In C++, you can initialize the variable by calling a lambda expression:

```
const int flags = [&] {
    int flags = 0;

    if (condition1) 
        flags |= 1;
    ....
    if (conditionX)
        flags |= Y;

    return flags;
}();
```

In either language, GCC and Clang (and other GCC-compatible compilers) have a similar feature as an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

```
const int flags = ({
    int flags = 0;

    if (condition1) 
        flags |= 1;
    ....
    if (conditionX)
        flags |= Y;

    flags;
});
```

Comment: I like this. Note that this solution is only for C++.

Comment: @Nybble If you're unconcerned with portability, GCC and Clang offer [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) which work similarly in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Statement Expression is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You could just delegate the initialization of your variable to a function and assign its return value to the `const` version you need. For instance:

```
int bar() {
    int flags = 0;
    if (condition1) {
        flags |= 1;
    }
    // ...
    return flags;
}

void foo() {
    int const c_flags = bar();
    // ...
}
```

That assumes that you can embed `condition1`, ..., `conditionX` into `bar`. If not you could always use functors (lambdas) to test your predicates and update `flags` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

IMO it's a coding style issue.

```
int get_flags() {
  int flags;
  ....
  if (condition1) 
      flags |= 1;
  ....
  if (conditionX)
      flags |= Y;
  ....
  return flags;
}
void foo() {
  const int flags = get_flags();
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a non-issue... but should it be an actual problem, then proper program design can easily solve it:

```
void foo() {
  int flags;

  flags = do_stuff_with(flags);

  take_decisions_based_on(flags);
}
```

where the functions would be something like:

```
int do_stuff_with (int something);

void take_decisions_based_on (int something);
```

You don't even need to apply const correctness since the functions will only be dealing with local copies of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

What about using ternary operator:

```
const int flags = condition1 ? 1 : (condition2 ? 2 : (conditionX ? Y : default_value))
```